# pub serve not finding files under lib

Tags: dart, angular

I'm testing with the developer preview of Angular Version 2 and serving it up using pub serve

I would like to estalblish a convention to structure my files inside /lib/ as follows:

```
└── project/lib/root
    ├── root.css
    ├── root.dart
    └── root.html
└── project/web/
    ├── index.html
    └── index.dart
```

In my /web/index.dart file i am successfully able to initialize the @View and @Component from root.dart

However, when i preview in Dartium via pub serve -  i can't seem to serve up /lib/root/root.html

```
@Component(
    selector: 'jroot'
)
@View(
    templateUrl: '../../lib/root/root.html',
    directives: const [If]
)
class Root {
  String content = 'Root - This is the entry point to the component';
  List<Times> list;

  Root(){
    print('RootComponent Init');
  }
}
```

*Dartium Console:*

```
GET http://localhost:8080/lib/root/root.html 404 (Not Found)
```

I've been reading the documents for polymer here which states:

> "Non-Dart files under lib must use relative paths to import assets under lib:"

```
https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/app-directories.html

<!-- lib/a5/a6/a6.html imports lib/a4.html -->
<link rel="import" href="../../a4.html">
```

Running a python simple web server seems to work, so the problems is with pub serve:

python -m SimpleHTTPServer

**Question:** How do a configure pub serve to work with nested html files from the lib folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have the proper entry points on your pubspec.yaml transformers:

```
name: 'project'
version: 0.0.1
dependencies:
  angular2: '2.0.0-alpha.23'
  browser: any
transformers:
- angular2:
    entry_points:
        - web/index.dart  //this
    reflection_entry_points:
        - web/index.dart  //this
```

Then I think this should work

```
templateUrl: 'packages/project/root/root.html',
```

or just

```
templateUrl: 'root.html',
```